# Generate a coredump from crashed process attached to ddd/dbx

Tags: unix, solaris, coredump, dbx, ddd-debugger

I'm running dbx in ddd on Solaris. The attached process has crashed and I can examine the stack in the debugger.

I want to save this core dump to disk for later.

Google shows me several ways to create a core dump but none of them are ddd/dbx commands. `gcore` can't grab the process because dbx is already holding it.

So how do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with `gcore -F` (force even if process is attached to a debugger) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good question.  The only thing I can think of is to detach from the process with dbx, and then use gcore to create the core dump.  But if the process was started by dbx, it might refuse to detach from it.  Also, detaching from a faulted process might not work correctly, and the process might go away.